# adding multiselection to ul li in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is a snippet I used to create a `<ul>` list. I will be adding `<li>` with the help of jQuery. Please help me with how to add multi-selection to `<li>` items.

```
<div class="projects">
     <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
  
     </ul>
</div>
```

li elements are added as below

```
$('#projects-menu').append("<li id='li-select' value = '"+String.raw`${value[projectName]}`+"'>"+projectName+"</li>")
```

The result is something as shown in the image.

[image: Result]

Comment: If you're okay with using plugins: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/User-friendly-Multi-select-List-Plugin-jQuery-multi-list.html

Answer (score 0):

This works here. Import jQuery first and use a select tag instead of ul:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

var options = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];

$("#projects-menu").append(new Option('Select a fruit', 0, true, true)).trigger("change"); 
// Default option

options.forEach(o => $("#projects-menu").append(new Option(o, o, false, false)).trigger("change"));

$("#projects-menu").on("change", function () {
                const selectedValue = $(this).val();
                console.log(selectedValue);
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Oh ok, so you could use a variable like `var selectedItems = [];` and add and remove selected items to it. `$('li').on("click", function() { selectedItems.push($(this)) })`

Answer (score -1):

We can use this follow steps:
-1st you can put jQuery links in the head section

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.map"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd step is to use  with an id attribute
then we can use javascript a JSON.JS